# What are the performance penalties, if any, of KEYS_ONLY versus ALL when projecting attributes in a DynamoDB GlobalSecondaryIndex?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

If you don't project all the attributes then if you query by that index by definition you can only get the hash of that value from the result and then perform another query using the hash key to get all the other data.

This would be 2 queries just to get 1 item. Naturally that doesn't make a lot of sense so there must be some reasons why it's advantageous to project only KEY attributes.

Does it speed up replication across the GSI since there are less values to copy thereby increasing chance of a fully consistent read taking place?

Does it lower read / write costs to the table overall as a whole?

Comment: Read unit are measured in KB so, KEY only will consume less units, and may be enough for some use case (like counter and "does this thing exist")

Comment: Great point Boris bandwidth is definitely a consideration. Do you know if projection type affects replication speed of globlsecondaryindexes though? I'm wondering about performance and reducing time until consistency is reached across GSI's.